# Refrigerator freezing on top up to 9 degrees warmer on lower shelves

Tags: refrigerator, temperature

Side by side Frigidaire 6 months old.  Has done this before, but was working fine by the time the repairman showed up.  It is NOT overloaded.  It does usually run a degree or two different, but not 9 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the evaporator coils are freezing up and the fan is unable to keep the air moving, it could be a faulty defrost timer, this is unacceptable for a new fridge.